# Retrieve a value through three tables in a single Query

Tags: php, sql, join

I have been trying to understand joins for a while now, I've noticed quite a few examples showing how to retrieve a value based on a two-table query using a left / inner join. I will try to draw out my example for you all, hopefully it will aid in the explanation of my question.

```
Table 1:
project_id  |  project_name
    1          super-project

Table 2:
project_id  |  course_id       ---> project_id and course_id are foreign keys here.
    1              3

Table 3:
course_id  |  course_name      ---> course_id is a primary key here
    3      |  Writing 101
```

**My Goal:**

I would like to be able to return "Writing 101" by using the project_id. So, if I know the project_id is 1, I would query the db to find that the course_id associated with the current project is `3`. I would then use the course_id of `3` to query table 3 and find that the related course_name is `writing 101`.

***Is there a way to do this in a single query using  join of some sort?***

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
select course_name from Table3
inner join Table2
on Table2.course_id = Table3.course_id
where Table2.project_id = 1
```

**Notice there is only 1 join needed!**

Also note that if the project_id = 1 is present in more than one course all of those courses will appear.

> Can you explain why only one join is needed as opposed to the answer below which requires two joins?

The other answer does not require two joins. As the project_id is present in the "middle" table there is no need to look for it in Table1. Now, if you require the name of the project (which is not the case because you didn't mention that in the question) then you would have to join the Table1

Comment: Can you explain why only one join is needed as opposed to the answer below which requires two joins?

Comment: Simple.  You don't actually need access to "Table 1" because the value your where clause depends on is in "Table 2".  Hence you just need the join between "Table 2" and "Table 3"

Comment: t2 has project id, t2 connects to t3 (via course_id ) which has the value you want.

Comment: Ah, because project_id is a foreign key, I think that would be the reason you are trying to explain to me. So, if I *did* need a column's value from table 1, I would then need to use a second join?

Comment: Yeap. If you had the `project_name` instead, then you'd need that extra join with `Table1` and the `where` clause would look like this: `WHERE Table1.project_name = 'super-project'`.

Comment: I'm going to give this a go, then. I appreciate the explanations.

Answer (score 1):

Here you go:

```
SELECT c.course_name
FROM Table3 c
INNER JOIN Table2 pc ON pc.course_id = c.course_id
INNER JOIN Table1 p ON p.project_id = pc.project_id
WHERE project_id = 1
```

Comment: woah,  Ok let me decipher this bad boy :) Also, what does the "c" represent in "c.course_name" and "from table3 c" ?

Comment: *FROM Table3 c* is the same as *FROM Table3 as c* which means lets call Table3 'c' to make life easier for ourself